# Does Razor View engine manipulates the selected item of a dropdown when field value is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I hope somebody can explain what's going on with this.
I have couple dropdownlists on my page which has the same item set (null, True, False). i can't understand how and why, when page rendered i see Razor selects the previous dropdowns selected item for the current one if the value is null.

Here is my code:

```
public class DdlViewModel
{
    public bool? Field1 { get; set; }
    public bool? Field2 { get; set; }
    public bool? Field3 { get; set; }
    public bool? Field4 { get; set; }
    public bool? Field5 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YesNoBlank { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult DDl()
{
    var selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Value = null, Text = ""},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "True", Text = "Yes"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "False", Text = "No"},
    };

    var viewModel = new DdlViewModel();
    viewModel.Field2 = true;
    viewModel.Field4 = false;
    viewModel.YesNoBlank = selectListItems;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and here is the view;

```
<body>
    <div>
        Field 1 @Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.Field1, Model.YesNoBlank)
        <br />
        Field 2 @Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.Field2, Model.YesNoBlank)
        <br />
        Field 3 @Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.Field3, Model.YesNoBlank)
        <br />
        Field 4 @Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.Field4, Model.YesNoBlank)
        <br />
        Field 5 @Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.Field5, Model.YesNoBlank)
    </div>
</body>
```

here is the result, which I actually expect Field 3 and 5 to be empty as it is for Field 1;
 [image]

**UPDATE**

Per Tetsuya Yamamoto's answer, I changed my code as below. That also did the trick. and didn't require any changes on my view.

```
public class DdlViewModel
{
    ...
    public SelectList YesNoBlank { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult DDl()
{
    var selectListItems = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Value = null, Text = ""},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "True", Text = "Yes"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "False", Text = "No"},
    }, "Value", "Text");

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using same `Model.YesNoBlank` for all dropdowns, you can pass null value to enforce selected value for third and fifth `DropDownListFor` like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.Field3, new SelectList(Model.YesNoBlank, "Value", "Text", null))

@Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.Field5, new SelectList(Model.YesNoBlank, "Value", "Text", null))
```

Note that the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` collection "remembers" last selected value setting when applying to a `DropDownListFor` (i.e. [`Selected` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectListItem_Selected) exists for this purpose), hence if the second dropdown's selected value set as `true`, the next dropdowns using same `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property will set with the same value until another value exists in list item is assigned as selected value.

The same behavior also exists when using `foreach` loop to generate `DropDownListFor` with same `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property as list items and containing selected value, as explained in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356924/multiple-html-dropdownlistfor-with-the-same-selectlist-set-selected-value).

In short, the `Nullable<bool>` property doesn't clear selected value from `Selected` property once it has been set. So, the answer is "no" because `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` selected value did not reset even if null value explicitly assigned, e.g. `viewModel.Field3 = null`.

Live example: [.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e8IFqx)

Related issue: [MVC Multiple DropDownLists from 1 List<SelectListItem>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880662/mvc-multiple-dropdownlists-from-1-listselectlistitem)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I little bit changed your suggestion and added an update on my post. Do you think that would make any difference performance-wise?